# center text of table data connected with colspan="2" with .css " Select td with attribute colspan="2" "

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

Hi I have a table where certain columns in a row are connected with the `colspan="2"` attribute.

In the moment it looks like this:

[image]

I want that the text of the connected columns in a row is centered, but only the text in the connected columns

The table data of this row  (unlimited ) has the following code

```
<tr class="row-4 even">    
<td colspan="2" class="column-3 footable-last-column" style="display: table-cell;">unlimited</td>
</tr>
```

I can not change the code of the table because it is automatically created by the Wordpress plugin `tablepress`

What I can do is to add a custom .css file.

My Question is, if it is possible to select only the table data with the attribute 
`colspan="2"` with .css, so that I can do `{ text-align: center }` only for table data with the attribute `colspan="2"`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The CSS selector `[attribute="value"]` is what you want, so you should add

```
td[colspan="2"] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to center the cell that spans two columns.

If you want to center cells that span any number of columns, you can use

```
td[colspan]:not([colspan="1"]) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

to select all cells that have a `colspan` attribute set to a value other than `1`.

Comment: The best answer on this subject. Thank You.

Comment: what if i am USING Div and tr class which convert that div to TR tag how to add colspan for div tag which refer as TR

Answer (score 22):

This should do the trick if you are applying the CSS inline:

```
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">unlimited</td>
```

Comment: what if i am USING Div and tr class which convert that div to TR tag how to add colspan for div tag which refer as TR