# Horizontally Centering text inside a table

Tags: html, css

I can't get text to center in my TDs that have a colspan greater than 1, I've added text-align center to every single tag and nothing.

HTML: ( I removed all but one of the items that wouldn't center I've left all the tags that are relevant to this text )

```css
div.OBJ {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
div.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr id="{{ParentObject.id}}">
      <td id="{{ParentObject.id}}" colspan="{{object.size}}" style="background-color:{{object.bgColor}}" data-begin="{{object.begin}}" data-end="{{object.end}}">
        {% multiply object.size colWidth as colSize %}
        <div id="{{object.id}}" class="OBJ" style="width:{{colSize}}%">
          <a id="{{object.id}}" href="link" title="hover text">
            <span id="{{object.id}}" class="object">
                            {{object.name}}
                        </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [center text of table data connected with colspan="2" with .css " Select td with attribute colspan="2" "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594610/center-text-of-table-data-connected-with-colspan-2-with-css-select-td-with)

Comment: Try adding `div {margin:auto;}` since there is width set on it.

Comment: The possible duplicate doesn't help because I'm using Django to make the colspans a variable width.  @jason

Comment: @Pangloss  doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

your problem is:

```
div.OBJ {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

`display: table-cell` lets the element behave like a `<td>` and most likely inherits something differently.

Comment: When I remove this it reverts everything to left center except the ones that are colspan greater than 1.  Those are moved closer to the center but are sometimes really far left of center.

Comment: use the `!IMPORTANT` decleration

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have is `div.OBJ` contains `display: table-cell`. Here's how it looks removed:

```css
div.OBJ {
  text-align: center;
}
div.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr id="{{ParentObject.id}}">
      <td id="{{ParentObject.id}}" colspan="{{object.size}}" style="background-color:{{object.bgColor}}" data-begin="{{object.begin}}" data-end="{{object.end}}">
        {% multiply object.size colWidth as colSize %}
        <div id="{{object.id}}" class="OBJ" style="width:{{colSize}}%">
          <a id="{{object.id}}" href="link" title="hover text">
            <span id="{{object.id}}" class="object">
                            {{object.name}}
                        </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed the display: table-cell
It sort of (they are left of center) centered the text in the TDs that are more than one column but the ones that are one column are now left aligned.
@analytalica